# Regex for comma separated string with/without spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want to create a Regex where I want to extract string that is satisfying pattern.

Input string can appear in below two possible ways

1. `type MyClass inherits SomeClass,SomeOtherClass implements Node`
2. `type MyClass inherits SomeClass, SomeOtherClass implements Node`

> **Note:** implements word can be anything like `extend`/`union`/`intersection` etc.

The regex should extract `"inherits SomeClass, SomeOtherClass"` string from the above input string.

I tried multiple SO answers and different online sources, but can't get success in the same. I used `/inherits\s(.*?)\s/mg` which only works for 1st case.

What would be regex to satisfy both the cases? Help would be appreciate.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pankajparkar/4kah7af3/5/)

Comment: What about this `/inherits\s+(.*)Class/mg` ?

Comment: Probably [`(inherits\s+.*?)\s+implements`](https://regex101.com/r/3yGCgi/2/) will solve the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew their could be any possibility of string instead of implements..

Comment: Then use [`/inherits\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3yGCgi/3/), see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kah7af3/6/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Fantastic, that's so accurate! would you mind to add an answer??

Comment: @PankajParkar Other possibilities like `throws`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 check updated question please.. but already wiktor already solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/inherits\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yGCgi/3/).

**Details**

- `inherits` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters,digits or underscores)
- `(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*` - zero or more (`*`) occurrences of:

  - `\s*,\s*` - a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /inherits\s+\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*/g;

var input1 = "type MyClass inherits SomeClass,SomeOtherClass implements Node";
var input2 = "type MyClass inherits SomeClass, SomeOtherClass implements Node";

var result1 = input1.match(regex);
var result2 = input2.match(regex);

document.write("result 1: "+ result1);
document.write("<br>")
document.write("\n result 2: "+ result2);
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks alot! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the string is followed by `implements`

```
var regex = /inherits\s+(.*)\s+(?=implements?)/mg;

var str1 = "type MyClass inherits SomeClass,SomeOtherClass implements Node";
var str2 = "type MyClass inherits SomeClass, SomeOtherClass implements Node";

str1.match( regex ) //["inherits SomeClass,SomeOtherClass "]

str2.match( regex ) //["inherits SomeClass, SomeOtherClass "]
```

Comment: Thanks for you so much, `implements` word can be anything. Check updated question